# Opening a pdf in Adobe Reader from browser in iOS using url-scheme

Tags: ios, url-scheme

If I check this: http://schemes.zwapp.com/
the url scheme for Adobe Reader in iPad is: com.adobe.Adobe-Reader:

So I created a link in my web-page pointing to:
com.adobe.Adobe-Reader://mysite.com/sample.pdf

Clicking the link launches Adobe Reader but it won't download and open the pdf from the url specified. I have tried various variations of the link including:

com.adobe.Adobe-Reader://http://mysite.com/sample.pdf

com.adobe.Adobe-Reader://edit?url=http://mysite.com/sample.pdf

but none of these work. Adobe Reader opens but it does not open the pdf (the link to pdf is fine, I checked by opening separately in browser).

What am I doing wrong? How can I make a app open a specific document by using its url scheme in the browser anchor link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you're doing anything wrong. According to [this Adobe thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/4418300), the Reader app doesn't (yet) support linked references to specific PDFs, but may in a future release. (Or if it does, they're not telling anyone how just yet).

There's an email contact to Adobe at the bottom of that thread that might be able to help more and/or that you might be able to bug to get this feature implemented sooner rather than later.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @UXUiOS. My bad I chose the app that did not support it. Anyways, can you please specify which of the 3 ways I mentioned is the correct way to link a document to open in an iPad app?

Comment: There is no single correct way: Any app that supports URL schemes can implement it any way it wants. It doesn't have to follow any HTML conventions. Suggestion: In my apps, I create my own UIWebView to view PDFs. Then it's as simple as opening your URL in the UIWebView and you don't have to rely on other apps.

Comment: Thanks UXUiOS..
I tried with iAnnonate instead and it worked.